# Play2-mini and Akka2 for HTTP gateway

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, play2-mini

I'm evaluating the possibility of using [Play2-mini](https://github.com/typesafehub/play2-mini) with Scala to develop a service that will sit between a mobile client and existing web service. I'm looking for the simplest possible example of a piece of code where Play2-mini implements a server and a client. Ideally the client will use Akka2 actors.

With this question, I'm trying to find out how it is done, but also to see how Play2-Mini and Akka2 should co-operate. Since Play2-Mini appears to be the replacement for the Akka HTTP modules.

Play2-mini contains the following code example, in which I created two TODO's. If someone can help me with some sample code to get started, I will be really grateful.

```
package com.example

import com.typesafe.play.mini._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._

object App extends Application {
  def route = {
    case GET(Path("/testservice")) & QueryString(qs) => Action{ request=>
      println(request.body)
      //TODO Take parameter and content from the request them pass it to the back-end server
      //TODO Receive a response from the back-end server and pass it back as a response
      Ok(<h1>Server response: String {result}</h1>).as("text/html")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer is not what you expected and needs some edits. Or clarify if I missed the point. You might have thought that you needed to use actors explicitly for your HTTP gateway, but it's not the case. The simplest way is to use `Async` and `play.api.libs.ws.WS` and let Play framework manage Akka actors.

Comment: Thanks for the friendly help @romusz. The answer looks perfect ;-) but I have not had the chance to implement it in my server, which is why my response was a bit sluggish. Something else landed on my table, but I'll get to it within the next day or two. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the implementation of your example.

Add the following imports:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import play.api.mvc.BodyParsers.parse
import scala.xml.XML
```

Add the following route:

```
case GET(Path("/testservice")) & QueryString(qs) => Action{ request =>
    Async {
      val backendUrl = QueryString(qs,"target") map (_.get(0)) getOrElse("http://localhost:8080/api/token")
      val tokenData = QueryString(qs,"data") map (_.get(0)) getOrElse("<auth>john</auth>")
      WS.url(backendUrl).post(XML loadString tokenData).map { response =>
      Ok(<html><h1>Posted to {backendUrl}</h1>
         <body>
           <div><p><b>Request body:</b></p>{tokenData}</div>
           <div><p><b>Response body:</b></p>{response.body}</div>
         </body></html>).as("text/html") }
      }
    }
```

All it does, is forwarding a `GET` request to a back-end serivce as a `POST` request. The back-end service is specified in the request parameter as `target` and the body for the POST request is specified in the request parameter as `data` (must be valid XML). As a bonus the request is handled asynchronously (hence `Async`). Once the response from the back-end service is received the front-end service responds with some basic HTML showing the back-end service response.

If you wanted to use request body, I would suggest adding the following `POST` route rather than `GET` (again, in this implementation body must be a valid XML):

```
case POST(Path("/testservice")) & QueryString(qs) => Action(parse.tolerantXml){ request =>
    Async {
      val backendUrl = QueryString(qs,"target") map (_.get(0)) getOrElse("http://localhost:8080/api/token")
      WS.url(backendUrl).post(request.body).map { response =>
      Ok(<html><h1>Posted to {backendUrl}</h1>
         <body>
           <div><p><b>Request body:</b></p>{request.body}</div>
           <div><p><b>Response body:</b></p>{response.body}</div>
         </body></html>).as("text/html") }
      }
    }
```

So as you can see, for your HTTP Gateway you can use `Async` and `play.api.libs.ws.WS` with Akka under the hood working to provide asynchronous handling (no explicit Actors required). Good luck with your Play2/Akka2 project.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer by romusz

Another way to make a (blocking) HTTP GET request:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS.WSRequestHolder  
import play.api.libs.ws.WS.url  
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise  
import play.api.libs.ws.Response

val wsRequestHolder: WSRequestHolder = url("http://yourservice.com")  
val promiseResponse: Promise[Response] = wsRequestHolder.get()  
val response = promiseResponse.await.get

println("HTTP status code: " + response.status)
println("HTTP body: " + response.body)
```